# Java (swing): Annoyance resizing JFrame by dragging the bottom left corner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img845/796/15881822.jpg]

The black is JFrame content and the red one is JPanel's.
This happens a lot when resizing the JFrame. A little less, when resizing the frame from upper left corner, but still happens.
The panel is not able to keep up with the frame change.

Why, is it "fixable" ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Be a bit more specific and please provide some code. Otherwise we do not know what to answer.

Comment: @Howard Desired behaviour is content (more precisely JPanel which holds all the child elements aswell) resizing itself more "slickly" or faster during JFrame size change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines provide the desired behavior on a JFrame:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBackground(Color.black);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        pack();
    }
}
```